# FFMPEG video conversion to FLV without losing quality?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using below command in php for converting all videos to flv. It's working proper but quality is bad after conversion. I want to retain quality after conversion.

```
$wide=$file['video']['resolution_x'];
$tall=$file['video']['resolution_y']; 

exec("ffmpeg -i test.anyformate  -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s ".$wide."x".$tall." flvideo/$vid.flv");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this, but you have to compile FFmpeg and x264 (codec) yourself and achieve the lossless conversion like this:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -crf 22 -threads 0 output.flv`

The steps are detailed here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1249838&p=7850605#post7850605

Comment: should work with all formats FFmpeg is able to read/process. x264 codec gives you the lossless conversion you need.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Supported-File-Formats_002c-Codecs-or-Features

Comment: x264 codec is included in FFMPEG or need to install it separately?

Comment: Try running the command I mentioned for your file in command line manually; then you'll know. If it errors, you might have to compile from source as outlined in the article I've linked to.

Comment: Here's a quick guide on compiling FFmpeg and x264 codec: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20quickly%20compile%20FFmpeg%20with%20libx264%20%28x264,%20H.264%29